# Can the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation be translated directly into two dimensions with constant gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science, propulsion

By taking the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation

$$
\Delta v=v_{\mathrm{e}} \ln \frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}}$$
where $ v_e $ is velocity at which mass is being dispersed, can the same be done with vectors such that
$$\Delta \vec{v}=\vec{v}_{\mathrm{e}} \ln \frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}}$$

[image]

Suppose that the rocket is dispersing mass at the angle $\theta$ from the horizon - could one then assume:

$$
\Delta v_{x}=\left|v_{e}\right| \cdot \cos \theta \cdot \ln \frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}}
$$

and

$$
\Delta v_{y}=\left|v_{e}\right| \cdot \sin \theta \cdot \ln \frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}}
$$

and could you even account for (a constant) gravity in the $y$-direction as such?:

$$
\Delta v_{y}=\left|v_{e}\right| \cdot \sin \theta \cdot \ln \frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}}-g \cdot t
$$

Comment: you cannot add gravity that way